# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, equality

I am using this great vanilla JavaScript version of the jQuery `on()` created by [ChrisFerdinandi](https://gomakethings.com/a-vanilla-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-on-method/)

```
var on = function (event, elem, callback, capture) {
        if (typeof elem === 'function') {
            capture = callback;
            callback = elem;
            elem = window;
        }
        capture = capture ? true : false;
        elem = typeof elem === 'string' ? document.querySelector(elem) : elem;
        if (!elem) return;
        elem.addEventListener(event, callback, capture);
    };
```

And I'm hitting an error at this line:

```
elem = typeof elem === 'string' ? document.querySelector(elem);
```

When I utilize the function here:

```
on('mouseover', '#' + rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function () {
```

and here:

```
on('mouseout', '#' + rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function () {
```

Looks like I need a third option, but not sure how to start...

or should I just utilize `==` like Kyle Simpson would suggest instead?

```
elem = typeof elem === 'string' ? document.querySelector(elem) : elem;
```

Comment: Looks like `rollOverCollectionA[i].id` doesn't have a value, could you log its value before entering the function?

Comment: It means `rollOverCollectionA[i].id` is empty, ie `""` so your selector becomes just `#` nothing else which isnt valid selector

Comment: If you've got an array with elements in it, just pass the element; there's no reason to go back to the DOM and find it again. That's the whole point of that test to see whether `elem` is a string.

Comment: I have a example working in a codepen, https://codepen.io/antonioOrtiz/pen/aQoMNQ?editors=1010 Not sure why it isn't working in the environment which will eventually go to production.